# How do I fully configure Cinnamon?

Tags: suspend, configuration, cinnamon

I've installed Cinnamon over LXDE in Ubuntu 15.10, and I removed everything LXDE-related.

When the computer wakes from sleep (i.e, when I close and reopen the lid), I enter my password (into a non-Cinnamon unlocker) to unlock it, and the Cinnamon panel has vanished.

As far as I can tell, Cinnamon is configured properly, and comes back after a reboot, but as soon as I sleep the PC again, it vanishes. My desklets stay working, as do some other Cinnamon extensions, just the panel vanishes.

I could run `cinnamon --replace` but that would not honour my user's configurations, nor is it what I want to have to do every wakeup.

Am I missing a package? What can I do?

Here's cinnamon's LookingGlass log:

```
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:53.931Z Cinnamon.AppSystem.get_default() started in 418 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:53.944Z loading user theme: /home/cat/.themes/Numix-Blue-Cinnamon/cinnamon/cinnamon.css
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:53.980Z added icon directory: /home/cat/.themes/Numix-Blue-Cinnamon/cinnamon
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.076Z PlacesManager: Updating devices
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.157Z Loaded extension gTile@shuairan in 36 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.162Z Loaded extension DesktopCube@yare in 5 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.163Z loaded at Fri Jan 01 2016 20:33:54 GMT-0500 (EST)
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.864Z Loaded applet menu@cinnamon.org in 697 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.887Z Role locked: panellauncher
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.888Z Loaded applet panel-launchers@cinnamon.org in 23 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.896Z Loaded applet expo@cinnamon.org in 8 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.906Z Loaded applet workspace-switcher@cinnamon.org in 9 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.916Z Role locked: notifications
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.921Z Loaded applet notifications@cinnamon.org in 15 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.933Z Role locked: windowlist
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.934Z Loaded applet window-list@cinnamon.org in 13 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:54.987Z Loaded applet sound@cinnamon.org in 53 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.025Z Loaded applet keyboard@cinnamon.org in 36 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.044Z Loaded applet power@cinnamon.org in 19 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.122Z Loaded applet network@cinnamon.org in 77 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.133Z Loaded applet removable-drives@cinnamon.org in 11 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.142Z Loaded applet systray@cinnamon.org in 8 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.165Z Loaded applet calendar@cinnamon.org in 21 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.186Z Loaded applet user@cinnamon.org in 21 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.202Z Loaded applet SW++@mohammad-sn in 15 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.202Z AppletManager.init() started in 1039 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.208Z Config file /home/cat/.local/share/cinnamon/desklets/TimeAndDate@nightflame/metadata.json
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.212Z Loaded desklet TimeAndDate@nightflame in 9 ms
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:55.215Z Cinnamon took 1730 ms to start
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:56.654Z Adding systray: wallch indicator (20x20px)
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:56.655Z Resized wallch indicator (16x16px)
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:57.155Z Resized wallch indicator (15x15px)
info t=2016-01-02T01:33:59.402Z PlacesManager: Updating devices
info t=2016-01-02T04:11:24.828Z PlacesManager: Updating devices
```

Comment: Does it work when using `cinnamon-screensaver` as the locker instead of the one you are currently using? Try it by removing your current one (find out which one with `dpkg -l | grep screensaver`) and install `cinnamon-screensaver`, then log out and in again.

Comment: I just removed `gnome-screensaver`, and `cinnamon-screensaver` was already installed, so I'll logout and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `gnome-screensaver` and ran `apt install cinnamon*` because some parts of cinnamon had not been installed, and the problem was solved.